# mongo-migrate up No migrations found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, migration

I develop a Node JS application in TypeScript.

I want to build migration scripts for database creation and collection initialization on mongodb. I want to use the [mongo-migrate-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-migrate-ts) package to do this. I've followed the example in the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-migrate-ts) step-by-step, typing the suggested commands in succession, but the last command, mongo-migrate-up, doesn't find the migrations.

1. `mongo-migrate init` the *migrations.json* file is generated

```
{
  "uri": "mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017",
  "database": "db",
  "options": {
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "useUnifiedTopology": true
  },
  "migrationsDir": "migrations",
  "migrationsCollection": "migrations_changelog"
}
```

2. `mongo-migrate new` the *migrations* directory and the *1696001448527_Migration.ts* file are generated

```
import { Db } from 'mongodb'
import { MigrationInterface } from 'mongo-migrate-ts';

export class Migration1696001448527 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(db: Db): Promise<any> {
    await db.createCollection('my_collection');
  }

  public async down(db: Db): Promise<any> {
    await db.dropCollection('my_collection');
  }
}
```

3. `mongo-migrate up`

After this third command, I get the following error:
`⚠ No migrations found`

I need your help please to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to compile your migration file take a look at the section "Compile and up all migrations" section in mongo-migrate-ts documentation:

> tsc migrations/index.js && node build/migrations/index.js up